# MvxTableViewCell BackgroudColor binding fails on iPad but work on simulator

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. The binding works fine on the simulator but fails on the real device - iPad.

```
public RunSheetItemView (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
{
    this.DelayBind (() => {
    var set = this.CreateBindingSet<RunSheetItemView, RunSheetItemViewModel>();

    set.Bind(this).For(v => v.BackgroundColor).To(vm  => vm.Status).WithConversion("InspectionStatusColorConverter");
    set.Apply();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it, the linker optimisation is causing the problem Add the following to the LinkerPleaseInclude.cs file

```
public class LinkerIncludePlease
{
        public void Include(MvxTableViewCell vc)
        {
            vc.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
        }
}
```